# SetOneShotPreviewCallback() only called once within loop

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I have the following code:

```
    for (int ii = 0; ii < nOfPictures; ii++){
            mCamera.startPreview();
            mCamera.setOneShotPreviewCallback(this);
    }
```

However, setOneShotPreviewCallback() only gets called once.  I run it in debugging mode and it stops at the breakpoint of the method call during every iteration, but stops only once in the breakpoint located in OnPreviewFrame().

It also appears setOneShotPreviewCallback() is on the same thread as the loop, if that is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Per the [`setOneShotPreviewCallback()` javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setOneShotPreviewCallback%28android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback%29),

> Installs a callback to be invoked for the next preview frame in addition to displaying it on the screen. After one invocation, the callback is cleared. This method can be called any time, even when preview is live. Any other preview callbacks are overridden.

Comment: Well, what I didn't realize was even though the screen is displaying a live preview, it wouldn't technically run OnPreviewFrame() since the main thread was sharing between this loop and the actual passing of preview frame data.  So there wasn't a "new frame" to even call setoneshotpreviewcallback() since it was in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to run startPreview() in a different thread, but I believe the previewing of frames must be done in the UI thread.  Perhaps the entire camera would've had to run on a different thread. But due to the ease of work, I put the loop in a new thread and called setOneShotPreviewCallback() as preview frames were concurrently being fed to onPreviewFrame() while the loop was running.

The code I used:

```
    Thread preview_thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {             

            for (int ii = 0; ii < numOfPictures; ii++){
            executeOneShotPreviewCallback();
            }
           }
        }, "one_shot_prev_callback_thread");
        preview_thread.start();
```

I had to use a helper function (executeOneShotPreviewCallback()) to perform the actual callback since the callback wasn't visible to the thread.